# Comparing is one NSString greater or less then another NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to understand comparing `NSString` routine. Please consider the following code:

```
// String

    NSString *str1 = @"This is a string A";

    NSString *str2 = @"This is a string B";

    NSString *res;

    NSComparisonResult compareResult;

compareResult = [str1 compare:str2];

    if (compareResult == NSOrderedAscending)
        NSLog(@"str1 < str2");

    if (compareResult == NSOrderedSame)
        NSLog(@"str1 == str2");
    else // must be NSOrderedDescending
        NSLog(@"str1 > str2");
```

My first question is, how could we determine is `NSString` greater or less then another one? Its not a number, so how exactly we determine it?

`NSString` consist of Unichar characters that are 16 bits size. Maybe compiler determine actual size of each string and compare it?

My second question is:
[image]

All conditions are met. How could that happen? Strings are different and we got all of 3 possible results - str1 is greater then str2, less then str2, and equal.

Comment: String comparisons do a lexical ordering based on each character. In simplified terms it basically does an alphabetic comparison. "B" is greater than "A" for example since B comes after A. Now expand that to cover every Unicode character.

Comment: Note that the comparison results in order, not more or less.

Comment: Read the fine specification.  (But the above code could not possibly produce the above console output.)

Comment: @HotLicks yeah, equal statement should not be here, the code produce it wasn't include in that topic. Sorry about that.

Comment: If `compareResult` is NSOrderedAscending then it's not NSOrderedSame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the comparison results in order, not greater than or less than. Do not equate order to more than or less than.

Order by convention is based on alphabet order.

While length is a characteristic of a string it is a little more complicated than that with unicode since a single character may require more than a single unicode code point.

Also `NSString` is not a string of unichars, but seems to be (the actual implementation is opaque) a sequence or UTF-16 code points.

The code:

```
if (compareResult == NSOrderedAscending)
    NSLog(@"str1 < str2");

if (compareResult == NSOrderedSame)
    NSLog(@"str1 == str2");
else // must be NSOrderedDescending
    NSLog(@"str1 > str2");
```

is flawed, it should be (notice the `else if`):

```
if (compareResult == NSOrderedAscending)
    NSLog(@"str1 preceeds str2");
else if (compareResult == NSOrderedSame)
    NSLog(@"str1 is the same as str2");
else // must be NSOrderedDescending
    NSLog(@"str1 follows str2");
```

Resulting in the output:

> str1 preceeds str2

Comment: if i understand correct, in if (compareResult == NSOrderedSame)
    NSLog(@"str1 == str2");
else // must be NSOrderedDescending
    NSLog(@"str1 > str2"); second line is printing NSLog for condition, when str1 precede str2?

Comment: In the question code ths second `if` statement will always execute, and always log a value. That is not want you want, you only want the second `if` statement to execute if the first `if` statement is not true.

Comment: i did some testing with code, when i change str1 to @"a" and str2 to @"b" i got result str1 precedes str2. When i made str1 = @"b" and str2 = @"a" (swap values) i got same result. That look kind of odd and confusing, why is this happening?

Comment: yeah i found mistake. Thank you Zaph, great answer, very easy to understand now.

Answer (score 3):

this is a really complex question, and some of the details are described here:

http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/

one example:
string_1 consists of ('b', DIAERESIS, 'a')
string_2 consists of ('b', 'ä')
('ä' is a 'a' with DIAERESIS (the two dots))
both are rendered to 'bä'
both strings contain 2 glyphs
string_1 contains 3 code points
string_2 contains 2 code points
in UTF-16 (the native NSString encoding) string_1 has a length of 6 bytes and string_2 has a length of 4 bytes. The NSString -length of them is 3 and 2.

this means, you shouldn't think that two strings are different just because they have different `length` ;)

both strings are equal according to NSString comparison rules.

[string_1 compare:string_2] will return NSOrderedSame
[string_1 isEqual:string_2] will return YES

... then there is case-insensitive-compare, and then there is localization-aware-compare...

Comment: thank you, answer is great, but would you be so kind to provide example with another strings? Im sorry, but I'm not understand why they are equal :(

Comment: I'm just confused in DIAERESIS, sorry. Anyway i appreciate your help.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban - Some Kaopectate might help that.

Answer (score 2):

In cocoa `compare:` returns one of three codes:

```
enum {
   NSOrderedAscending = -1,
   NSOrderedSame,
   NSOrderedDescending 
};
typedef NSInteger NSComparisonResult;
```

As you see, it does not use greater or less, but descending, ascending and same.

for sorting of numbers it matches <,>, ==, but in strings it matches alphabetical order.

---

When comparing strings be aware of the `compare:`-alernatives

- `- caseInsensitiveCompare:` @"ABC" and @"abc" are considered same
- `- localizedCompare:` as compare but knows how to handle language specific alphabets
- `- localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` combining the 2 previous
- …

Comment: do you actually want to order string by length?

Comment: I'm just wondering in ways we could compare two string. Because they are actually just chunk of bytes and I'm interesting how Xcode does comparing.

Comment: in that context i refer to Xcode to "machine, that understand our code". Sorry for miss understanding :)

Comment: it doesn't understand your code. it doesn't compile it, it doesn't run it.